# struggling with Django Chosen Form

Tags: django, jquery-chosen

I'm a new developer and I've come across a javascript library called Chosen.js which would work wonderful for my schools senior project.  My problem is I'm having issues getting started and getting the chosen form to show up using django-chosen.  I believe it's related to the invalid line break showing up in the linting tool and i'm missing something else.

After the pip install django-chosen I've added chosen to my installed files in settings.py as shown below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_python3_ldap',
    'chosen',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_filters',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]
```

Then I created my chosen form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import User, FacilityDimension
from django.forms import ModelForm
from widgets import ChosenSelectMultiple
from chosen import forms as chosenforms

class ChosenModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChosenModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            if self.fields[field].__class__.__name__ in ['ChoiceField', 'TypedChoiceField', 'MultipleChoiceField']:
                choices = self.fields[field].choices
                self.fields[field] = chosenforms.ChosenChoiceField(choices=choices)
            elif self.fields[field].__class__.__name__ in ['ModelChoiceField', 'ModelMultipleChoiceField']:
                queryset = self.fields[field].queryset
                self.fields[field] = chosenforms.ChosenModelChoiceField(queryset=queryset)

class FormFacilityDimension(ChosenModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FacilityDimension
```

After my form is created I use the following in my template, I receive no errors, but i'm not able to get it to show up:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        {% block extra_js %}
            {{ block.super }}
            {{ form.media }}
        {% endblock %}

I added the following javascript file, however my linting tool is showing invalid line break the first line which i can't seem to get rid of this may have something to do with my problem:



  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#id_coid_name').chosen();
      }
    )
      ;
```

I feel as if i'm missing a step and the tutorials online are mostly related to django_admin and seem incomplete.  Any advice in getting me up and running would be appreciated.

```
To expand on this i'm now getting the following error after adjusting my script tags.

[04/Jan/2018 14:20:19] "GET /account/profile/chosen.jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2849
Not Found: /account/profile/chosen.jquery.js
[04/Jan/2018 14:20:19] "GET /account/profile/chosen.jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2849
[04/Jan/2018 14:20:22] "GET /account/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20109
Not Found: /account/profile/chosen.jquery.js
[04/Jan/2018 14:20:22] "GET /account/profile/chosen.jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2849
```

For some reason it's trying to find it in /account/profile when the files are located in security/accounts/js/.  How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js scripts should live in your static folder together with the other static files of your website (css and images). This line:

```
<script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

causes the script to be loaded relative to the path of the current page. You should replace with

```
<script src= "{% static ‘security/accounts/js/chosen.jquery.js’ %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or whichever path your script is saved at relative to you STATIC_URL.

Comment: How can I find my STATIC_ROOT?  Right now I moved the files into Security/Accounts/Static/Accounts.  My STATIC URL is defined as /static/, is this the root you are referencing?  I get the following error after changing it:  django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 60: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
[04/Jan/2018 15:16:18] "GET /account/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 198992

Comment: line 60 is defined as:  <script src= "{% static ‘/accounts/js/chosen.jquery.js’ %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: You need to read up on static files (look at the Django documentation). {% load static %} near the top of your template will solve this error

Comment: Forget about STATIC_ROOT for now, that’s for your deployed app. STATIC_URL tells Django how to create the URL, in your case it would become /static/accounts/js/chosen.jquey.js relative to your project root (with runserver) or wherever you configure your sever to fetch files from (with Apache or nginx)

Comment: Alright, i attempted the above, but i gives me the following error:  Could not parse the remainder: '‘static/accounts/js/chosen.jquery.js’' from '‘static/accounts/js/chosen.jquery.js’

Comment: I have the wrong quote marks on mobile don’t copy paste from my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help dirk.  I no longer get the error message and it shows [04/Jan/2018 15:29:38] "GET /static/accounts/js/chosen.jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1697 in my console.  However, my template needs some work to get it to render there.  I'll work on that now i'm on the right track.  Once again thank you.